# Paypal sandbox giving internal server error

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, omnipay

I am working on PayPal integration with omnipay package. Firstly It was working fine but after some time it started to show internal server error. I reached on Google and found this problem is having from last few days. I want to know, how to solve this? is PayPal solved this issue or this issue is having due to any error in my script?

my script
[image]

Error page
[image]

Comment: That code looks ok, but you should check the data from $ response to see if there are any errors there. You should also consider switching to the REST gateway, it's more stable and better documented.

Comment: can you ;leaase explain how?

Comment: and what the error will show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer

The issue was I was passing wrong and cancel return URLs. These URLs are of my local server IP. when I removed this and applied a live server details it started again.

I also done some R & D and found PayPal is having this issue from last few months.

Thanks guys for your kind support!

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the downtime that sandbox has been experiencing over the last 24 hours. The internal teams were able to diagnose the problem and repair it. Can you please check to see if your code is working now? This was limited to sandbox and didn't affect production.

Comment: I got also this error: `<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.NullPointerException</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>`